# Django - Form is not saving to Db

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using for authentication extended `AbstractUser` and `ModelForm`. When I write on  `HTML` page only `{{ form }}` everything works fine, the form is submitting, but in the following case I've added some stylings, but now nothing works. Please, help me find the reason.

`HTML`:

```
    <form method='POST'>

    {% csrf_token %}    

        <div class="sign-up-user">

            <div class="sign-up-user-container">

                <div class="sign-up-user-left">
                    <label for="">{{form.username.label}}</label>
                    {{form.username}}<br>
                    <label for="">{{form.password.label}}</label>
                    {{form.password}}<br>
                    <label for="">{{form.branch.label}}</label><br>
                    {{form.branch}}<br>
                    <label for="">{{form.license_number.label}}</label>
                    {{form.license_number}}<br>
                    <label for="">{{form.fin_number.label}}</label>
                    {{form.fin_number}}<br>
                    <label for="">{{form.voen_number.label}}</label>
                    {{form.voen_number}}<br>
                </div>

            </div> 

            <input type="submit" value="Register User" class="sign-up-btn">

        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: you should add your form and view code to check where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include two lines to your HTML to understand whats going wrong:

```
{{ form.errors }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

This will display any errors that are associated with the form. If they dont then in your views do the following:

```
form = YourForm()
if form.is_valid():
    // Do things
else:
  print (form.errors)
  print(form.non_field_errors)
```

This will display some other errors that you are missing.